# Blackberry 10 HTML5 number input tag - the input field become empty after tapping away

Tags: html, blackberry-10, blackberry-webworks

I tried my HTML5 App on a Blackberry 10 phone (Q10), and I m using an input field for which the code is:

```
<input type="number" placeholder="myID" id="myId"/>
```

When testing, I can type my numric value , but once I tap on another field, or tap a button, the first input field become empty.

Strangely, when I change the tag "number" with "numeric", it works!
After verifying the HTML5 reference, I can see that no such "numeric" tag exists!

Does "number" works fine on Blackberry ? is there anything wrong with my code?

Comment: What OS version are you testing on (10.0, 10.1, 10.2) ?

Comment: I am using BB 10.1.0.2342  and I use JqueryMobile in my App

Answer (score 0):

I just tested it here on OS 10.1.0.4181 and it is working fine for me using your code. Do you happen to have anything onBlur listeners, maybe something else is going on there..=

Comment: I am using BB 10.1.0.2342 and I use JqueryMobile in my App. I don't have any onBlur listener in my code

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it worked well with `type="numeric"` is because your issue doesn't occur on `type="text"`.

**If the type of an input isn't specified or if the type is unknown then the browser will handle it as `type="text"`.**